# How to do module name alias for third party package

Tags: react-native

I have a app that created by *react-native init* command.
My app import websocket package which in turn require http package and cause error said "Unable to resolve module http".

i.e: myApp ->  3rd-module -> ws -> http

I try to work-around by install "@tradle/react-native-http", and added follow lines to my app's package json file:

```
"browser": { "http": "@tradle/react-native-http" }, 
"react-native": { "http": "@tradle/react-native-http" },
```

but it doesn't work.

I also try using babel-plugin-module-resolver but unluck either. Here is my .babelrc :

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    ["module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "@tradle/react-native-http": "http"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

How to do alias for my case? I research to fixing this problem by using webpack configuration, but don't know where is the configure file. After google, i think project created by *react-native init* use metro config instead of webpack.

Comment: Has verified that  just configure "browser" and "react-native" in package.json file work. Don't know why failed at begin.  Now my project run well without config .babelrc , metro.config.js or webpack.config.js.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    ["module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "http":"@tradle/react-native-http"
      }
    }]
```